# if result of argument satisfies a condition, how to return result immediately without having to restate the argument

Tags: python, if-statement

how to return a result of an argument that satisfies a condition without having to rewrite the argument in the return function.

e.g. (Long method)

```
if a+b > c:
    return a+b
```

is there a shorter syntax in the likes of-

```
if a+b > c
    return ans
```

(where in this case `ans == a+b`)

usually, the argument is much more complex than just a + b so it would save a lot of trouble retyping the entire argument

Comment: I guess you can: `if (ans:=a+b) > c: return ans` in the latest Python version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "walrus" operator:

```
if (ans := a + b) > c:
    return ans
```

in the latest Python version (3.8+).

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what the controversial "assignment expression" in Python 3.8 was intended for!

```
if (ans := a + b) > c:
    return ans
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Python3.8 you can use the `Walrus operator`

```
if (ans := a + b) > c:
    return ans
```

Or one-liner:

```
if (ans := a + b) > c: return ans
```

Check out the release notes: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the result to a variable

```
summed = a + b
if summed > c: 
    return summed
```